# R mutate a column by group in ifelse

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to mutate a column in R `data.table`.

Here's the example of my data.

```
df <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 stopId=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
category=c(1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2),
                 result = c('a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'))
```

My goal is to create a column using `if-else` command.
The column would be the first values of `groupId` group by `id`.

The point is when mutating, the values should be the same by group.

If the `category` is `NA`, then the result should be the last value of `groupId`.

This is the result I'm looking forward to.

```
   id groupId category result
1:  1       a        1      a
2:  1       b        1      a
3:  1       c        1      a
4:  2       a       NA      b
5:  2       c       NA      b
6:  2       b       NA      b
7:  3       c        2      c
8:  3       b        2      c
9:  3       a        2      c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `data.table`:

```
df[,result:=fifelse(is.na(category),last(stopId),first(stopId)),by=id][]

   id stopId category result
1:  1      a        1      a
2:  1      b        1      a
3:  1      c        1      a
4:  2      a       NA      c
5:  2      b       NA      c
6:  2      c       NA      c
7:  3      a        2      a
8:  3      b        2      a
9:  3      c        2      a
```

Answer (score 2):

As it's name, by using `first` and `last`,

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(resultt = ifelse(is.na(category), last(stopId), first(stopId)))
```

```
     id stopId category result resultt
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
1     1 a             1 a      a      
2     1 b             1 a      a      
3     1 c             1 a      a      
4     2 a            NA b      b      
5     2 c            NA b      b      
6     2 b            NA b      b      
7     3 c             2 c      c      
8     3 b             2 c      c      
9     3 a             2 c      c
```

Data you provided is different above...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.N` or `1` to index `stopId` per group

```
> df[, result := stopId[ifelse(is.na(category), .N, 1)], id][]
   id stopId category result
1:  1      a        1      a
2:  1      b        1      a
3:  1      c        1      a
4:  2      a       NA      c
5:  2      b       NA      c
6:  2      c       NA      c
7:  3      a        2      a
8:  3      b        2      a
9:  3      c        2      a
```

or shorter

```
> df[, result := stopId[c(1, .N)[is.na(category) + 1]], id][]
   id stopId category result
1:  1      a        1      a
2:  1      b        1      a
3:  1      c        1      a
4:  2      a       NA      c
5:  2      b       NA      c
6:  2      c       NA      c
7:  3      a        2      a
8:  3      b        2      a
9:  3      c        2      a
```

Comment: Why don't you use `data.table::fifelse`?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Yes, we can use `fifelse`: I just saw OP's request of using `ifelse`